# Hair texture is one big block vs being singular strands

Tags: texturing, particles, hair

running into a problem with this model (it's by pvrple serot0nin). I'll try my best to explain my dilemma here.

The hair, eyelashes, facial hair and eyebrows are all very blocky instead of them being individual strands. (You can see the strands of hair bound in a box)
[image]
[image]

Here's what the nodes look like for the hair:
[image]

Is it something to do with UV mapping? Would appreciate insight, thank you!

Comment: Is this being rendered in Eevee?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that above, sorry!

Comment: Have you chnged the Blend Mode to something other than oapque?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried all the options besides opaque and none of the other options seem to change it.

Comment: Hello maybe pack your image and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Could it be that the _Image Texture_ you use for the _Alpha_ is a black and white image containing the alpha information in the color, not the alpha channel? Then you would have to plug the _Color_ output into the _Alpha_ input of the _Principled BSDF_.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had the same issue before and never found a clear answer until now. Here's what worked for me:
[image: hairNodes]
The Color Ramp might not be necessary - and make sure you have your blend mode set to alpha clip! very important :)

[Here's a video that helped me figure it out, just in case you need it too.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udRLe6F6Z-0&list=PLQYdu5eTtv4OsZGYV_BWUxIfLVNGOmiIO&index=35)